# ALT + TAB Doesn't Work (Linux Mint MATE)

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, alt-tab

Somehow (I have no idea how) I broke my `ALT + TAB` functionality.  I'm using Linux Mint (MATE edition), and when I press `ALT + TAB` instead of switching to another application it very briefly shows the desktop, then returns me back to the application I was on.

I've tried enabling and disabling both the "Application Switcher" and "Static Application Switcher" in the CompizConfig, but neither has any effect.  Even if both are disabled, I still get the same "briefly show the desktop then return to the original app" behavior.

This made me think that I somehow had rebound my `ALT + TAB` keybinding, but when I go to Keyboard Shortcuts it does show "Move between windows, using a popup window" set to `ALT + TAB`.  If I change it (eg. to `CTRL + ALT + A`) the "show desktop briefly" behavior goes away ... unless I then do `CTRL + ALT + A`, in which case that behavior returns.

So in summary:

- I have a keybinding for `ALT + TAB` to "Move between windows, using a popup window", and this binding appears to trigger the "show desktop briefly" behavior even if I change it to a different binding
- I previously had "Static Application Switcher" enabled in CompizConfig, but whether I enable it, "Application Switcher", or none of the above, I see the same behavior

Thus, it seems I've somehow actually broken the "Move between windows, using a popup window" functionality, completely independent of Compiz ... and I have no idea how I can restore it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue. Disabling "software compositing window manager" worked for me:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/47066-ubuntu-mate-fixing-alt-+-tab-being-really-slow

Answer (score 0):

I had a fresh install and ran into this again, but found a new solution.

First, I installed and ran `dconf-editor` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` followed by `dconf-editor`).  This let me edit system settings using a friendly GUI (you could also just use the, already installed, command-line `gsettings to do the same thing).

Then I used it to change two settings:

```
org.mate.marco.global-keybindings.cycle-windows
org.mate.marco.global-keybindings.switch-windows
```

"cycle-windows" is an action which switches *immediately* the moment you press `ALT+TAB`, while "switch-windows" uses the pop-up window, causing slowness.  On my machine `switch-windows` was bound to `ALT+TAB`, while `cycle-windows` was set to `ALT+ESCAPE`.

All I had to do was switch those two values, and suddenly I had super-fast `ALT+TAB` switching!  And as an added bonus, `cycle-windows` limits itself to applications open on the current workspace (only).